# YANKING in Vim and Bash - are they opposite?

Tags: bash, vim, terminology

I have a very short question that I couldn't really find anywhere else upon googling, though to me this feels like a very natural question to ask, so maybe it's just I'm missing out on something.

So the word YANK feels like it means the opposite in Bash and Vim.

- In Bash, Copy and Paste is Kill and Yank. Hence we use `ctrl-y` to *paste* the text stored in the kill-ring (or, *yanking* text from kill ring, as in *pulling*.
- In Vim, Copy and Paste is Yank and Paste. Hence we use simply `p` to *paste*. But we use `y` to copy text to buffer.

Therefore it feels like to me that in Bash Yank is Copy and in Vim Yank is Paste. In English, Yank means "to pull", so I think it makes more sense to take Yank as Pulling data from buffer / kill-ring (so yank = paste).

But since I couldn't really find any discussion about this, I think there must be a very reasonable explanation for the above question. If anyone can help me understand this, it'll be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: so, what is the problem? ... what is there to understand?

Comment: "Pulling data from buffer" ... you do know that what you're editing in in Vim is called a buffer? https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ

Comment: Hey Jsotola, thanks for your comment. What I wanted to know was how/why the same word, yank, is used to mean different things (opposite direction).

Comment: Hey muru, yes, and you do know that "the operator **y** yanks a copy of the object which follows into the unnamed **buffer**? ;) https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/512065172ba2ab377e1030a82ab396370c5b2aec/doc/vi/vi.in#L794

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! That looks like a good learning resource :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` (or rather `readline` which is the line editing library used by bash) like most other shells since the early 80s has two line editing modes: `emacs` or `vi`, based on those two popular text editors.

Bash being the GNU shell and [GNU `emacs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Emacs) being one of GNU's star applications, the default mode there is `emacs`. You can switch between both with `set -o emacs` and `set -o vi` (also `bindkey -e`/`bindkey -v` in tcsh or zsh). Ksh also has `set -o gmacs` for [Gosling emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosling_Emacs) which is the one set as default on Solaris for instance.

So it's more about the different of meaning of the *yank* word in emacs vs vi.

Both emacs and vi were written in the late 70s long before either bash (1989) or vim (1991).

If you look at [the `vi` doc from 2BSD from 1979](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/512065172ba2ab377e1030a82ab396370c5b2aec/doc/vi/vi.in#L794):

> The operator **y** yanks a copy of the object which follows
> into the unnamed buffer.  If preceded by a buffer name, "x**y**,
> where x here is replaced by a letter **a−z**, it places the text
> in the named buffer.  The text can then be put back  in  the
> file with the commands **p** and **P**; **p** puts the text after or be‐
> low the cursor, while **P** puts the text before  or  above  the
> cursor.

Emacs doesn't have paste buffers, it has one *killring* that records text that has been *killed* or *copied* into it. The yanking is seen as being in the other direction, pulled from that killring as opposed to pulled from the text into the kill ring.

In [GNU emacs doc from around 1985](https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/emacs-history/blob/sources/www.tuhs.org/UnixArchive/4BSD/Distributions/4.3BSD/emacs/info/emacs#L2255), we find:

> Yanking is getting back text which was killed.  The usual way to
> move or copy text is to kill it and then yank it one or more times.

You'd see that bash has widgets from both editors that can bind to keys or key combinations:

```
$ bash -c 'bind -l' | grep -i yank
vi-yank-arg
vi-yank-pop
vi-yank-to
yank
yank-last-arg
yank-nth-arg
yank-pop
```

(the `vi` ones being mostly undocumented).

Default bindings:

```
$ bash -o vi -c 'bind -pm vi' | grep yank
"_": vi-yank-arg
# vi-yank-pop (not bound)
"Y": vi-yank-to
"y": vi-yank-to
"\C-y": yank
# yank-last-arg (not bound)
# yank-nth-arg (not bound)
# yank-pop (not bound)
$ bash -o vi -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' | grep yank
# vi-yank-arg (not bound)
# vi-yank-pop (not bound)
# vi-yank-to (not bound)
"\C-y": yank
# yank-last-arg (not bound)
# yank-nth-arg (not bound)
# yank-pop (not bound)
```

See how you still get a emacs-style <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> in vi insert mode; the undocumented `vi-yank-arg` bound on `_` also uses emacs-style terminology and behaves similarly to the `yank-last-arg` emacs widget. I have no idea what `vi-yank-pop` is meant to do. The `NEWS` file from the bash source distribution says it's *a vi-mode version of emacs-mode yank-pop*, though that doesn't make sense since vi has no kill-ring.

Comment: Hello Stephane, thank you so much for your answer! I didn’t know bash was using emacs, and so my question is actually about the difference between emacs and vi. It looks like the reason why they mean different (opposite) things is simply the design choice of the developers of vi and emacs.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding and including the links to those references as well!!